# Update Version History Programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, sharepoint-api

In my webpart I need to populate the data from the sharepoint lists and libraries.

I have an option to change the data in the UI and that should reflect the same in the lists/libraries when i click on save button.

Problem is even if I am not changing the data and click on save the  new versions are adding in my version history with out any changes..

This brings lot of problems in the audit.
I need solution/code that it should update the version history  only  if the item(list row) is changed when we click on save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this logic in the code itself. Before overwriting the list item, compare the list item with the previous version and if its same, do not overwrite.

Comment: this won't be possible..there will be dynamic controls more than 200 ...comparing every field will decreace the performance....i need know if any object like UpdateOnlyIfChanging like that...

Comment: Thanks Madhur..at last i did the same :( ..i don't find other way